# DirectX CreateRenderTargetView not properly initialized

Tags: directx, direct3d, directx-11, d3dx

For some reason I seem to be unable to initialize my `RenderTargetView` (it stays `NULL`) which causes an access violation.

Here is the line that should initialize the RenderTargetView:

```
hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(pBackBuffer, NULL, &g_pRenderTargetView);
```

`pBackBuffer` is the Back buffer and it gets a value, it isn't `NULL`. However, the rendertagetview stays `NULL` throughout the process. Any idea why?

Comment: You get the backbuffer like this right? ID3D11Texture2D* texture;
 mSwapChain->GetBuffer(0,__uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D),(void**)(&texture));

Answer (score 2):

In order to trace the DirectX11 errors, you'd better to create the D3D11 device with the [debug layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj200584%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it will print the error message to output window in Visual Studio when you launch your app.

```
    // Create device and swap chain
    HRESULT hr;
    UINT flags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT;
#if defined( DEBUG ) || defined( _DEBUG )
    flags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif 

    // Create device and swap chain
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL FeatureLevelsRequested = D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0; // Use d3d11
    UINT              numLevelsRequested = 1; // Number of levels 
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL FeatureLevelsSupported;

    if (FAILED (hr = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain( NULL, 
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        NULL,
        0,
        &FeatureLevelsRequested,
        numLevelsRequested,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        &sd_, 
        &swap_chain_,
        &d3ddevice_,
        &FeatureLevelsSupported,
        &immediate_context_)))
    {
        MessageBox(hWnd, L"Create device and swap chain failed!", L"Error", 0);
    }
```

Comment: I create the device using the DEBUG flag. However, there is no error message, simply the access violation error

Comment: Can you paste the full code which you initialize Direct3D11? from creating device to setrendertarget and viewport.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are failing to create the render target view because the second parameter is NULL:

```
HRESULT CreateRenderTargetView
(
  [in]   ID3D11Resource *pResource,
  [in]   const D3D11_RENDER_TARGET_VIEW_DESC *pDesc, <== You need to pass in a valid description
  [out]  ID3D11RenderTargetView **ppRTView
);
```

You can initialize it to something like this:

```
D3D11_RENDER_TARGET_VIEW_DESC desc = {0};
desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
desc.ViewDimension = D3D11_RTV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
```

Comment: It is perfectly allowed to use NULL for the second parameter. If you do so your view will be allowed to access the whole resource.